# puppet in not in code

Tags: puppet

I have this code...

```
if $hostname in $var_slave {
    file { 
        "/var/spool/cron/mysql":  
        ensure => present,
        owner => $mysqlUser,
        group => $mysqlGroup,
        mode => "0600",
        source => 'puppet:///modules/eikonappdbcron/mysql-slave',
    }
}
```

I want a way of checking if a value is not in a file.

I tried "if $hostname not in $var_master" but this doesn't work. After doing some research I believe I need to use an "!".  I can't get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppet does not have a single, combined "not in" operator.  Instead, it has [the `in` operator](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_expressions.html#in), and it has a general-purpose [boolean negation operator (`!`)](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_expressions.html#not).  You can use these together to write a compound expression that evaluates the condition you want.

If you already realized that, then perhaps you ran into a problem with [operator precedence](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_expressions.html#order-of-operations).  The negation operator has the higher precedence than does `in`.  Indeed, `!` has the highest precedence of any Puppet operator, so if its operand is intended to be a binary expression then you must enclose the operand in parentheses.

Thus, the negation of the boolean expression

```
$hostname in $var_master
```

is

```
! ($hostname in $var_master)
```

Comment: So would my finished bit of code look like this?                                         if ! ( $hostname in $var_master) {
    file { 
        "/var/spool/cron/mysql":  
        ensure => present,
        owner => $mysqlUser,
        group => $mysqlGroup,
        mode => "0600",
        source => 'puppet:///modules/eikonappdbcron/mysql-slave',
    }
}

Comment: @user2841861, as far as I can tell from what you have presented, yes, the finished code should look like that.